# Print numbers of a matrix in a wave pattern

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printf, nested-loops

I want the output to be `7 4 1 2 5 8 9 6 3` but it's coming out to be
`1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9`. How can I fix it, and what's the logic behind it so that I can print the reverse wave pattern, too?

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m;
    printf("enter no. of rows of 1st matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int n;
    printf("enter no. of columns of 1st matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[m][n];

    printf("\n enter the elements of 1st matrix");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // wave print
     for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < m-1; i++){
                printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0 - 1; i<=n-1; i++) {
                printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` is wrong in `n % 2`. You want to change direction based on which column is being process, not based on how many columns there are total.

Answer (score 3):

This condition

```
if(n % 2 == 0)
```

does not make sense. Instead you need to check the variable `j`.

```
if(j % 2 == 0)
```

and if `j` is an even number then the corresponding column must be outputted from bottom to top otherwise from top to bottom.

Also you can use only one inner for loop.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { m = 3, n = 3 };
    int a[m][n] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t even = i % 2 == 0, top = 0, bottom = m;

        for (size_t j = even ? bottom : top; j != (even ? top : bottom ); )
        {
            printf( "%d ", even ? a[--j][i] : a[j++][i] );
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
7 4 1 2 5 8 9 6 3
```

You could write a separate function that outputs the pattern. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * print_wave_pattern( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n], FILE *fp )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t even = i % 2 == 0, top = 0, bottom = m;

        for (size_t j = ( even ? bottom : top ), bound = ( even ? top : bottom ); j != bound; )
        {
            fprintf( fp, "%d ", even ? a[--j][i] : a[j++][i] );
        }
    }

    return fp;
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 3, n = 3;

    int a[m][n] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    fputc( '\n', print_wave_pattern( m, n, a, stdout ) );
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, btw, Is there any reason to prefer use `enum` over declaring m and n as `int`?

Comment: @EdherCarbajal I did not want to use a variable length array.:)

Answer (score 1):

First I translated the movement of the attached image into row `r` and column `c` indices (`r`, `c`):

```
(2, 0) (1, 0) (0, 0)
(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1)
(2, 2) (1, 2) (0, 2)
```

I observed that the slower moving value is the column index (`c`), so it must be the other loop going from from `0` through `N-1`.

Then, I examined the row index `r` and observed that the initial value is `initial = M-1` and direction of change is `summand = -1` for *even* column indices (`c % 2`). Otherwise, for odd column indices, `initial = 0` and `summand = 1`. Since there are only two sets of values you might as well just hoist them out of the loops. The `LAST()` macro is used to determine if we are printing the very last entry to switch between space and newline as the field terminator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LAST(r, c) ((r) == (M-1) * ((N-1) % 2) && (c) == N-1)

int main(void) {
    enum { M = 3, N = 3 }; // inspired by @VladfromMoscow
    int a[M][N] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    // wave print
    const int initial[] = {M-1, 0};
    const int summand[] = {-1, 1};
    for(int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        for(int r = initial[c%2]; r >= 0 && r < M; r += summand[c%2])
            printf("%d%c", a[r][c], " \n"[LAST(r, c)]);
}
```

Output:

```
7 4 1 2 5 8 9 6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to change a standard column traversal into an alternating transversal is a little transformation of the row index:

```
    for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
        for (int r = 0; r < m; ++r)
            printf("%d ", a[m-r-1 + c%2 * (2*r-m+1)][c]);
```

The idea here is that when have a counter `r` running from `0` to `n−1`, we want index `r` when going down a column but index `m-r-1` when going up a column. The difference between `r` and `n-r-1` is `2*r-m+1`. Since we start going up a column, we start with `m-r-1`. Then, when `c%2` is 1, instead of 0, we are going down a column, so we add the difference, and that gives us the index, `m-r-1 + c%2 * (2*r-m+1)`.

Complete code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int m;
    printf("Enter number of rows of 1st matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int n;
    printf("Enter number of columns of 1st matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[m][n];

    printf("\nEnter the elements of 1st matrix");
    for (int r = 0; r < m; ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
            scanf("%d", &a[r][c]);

    //  Wave print.
    for (int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
        for (int r = 0; r < m; ++r)
            printf("%d ", a[m-r-1 + c%2 * (2*r-m+1)][c]);
}
```

Comment: Calculate the row index on access instead of looping.  Neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the logic in a function that updates the cell coordinates:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void wave_first(int *x, int *y, int cols, int rows) {
    *x = 0;
    *y = rows - 1;
}

static inline bool wave_next(int *x, int *y, int cols, int rows) {
    if (*x & 1) {
        if (*y >= rows - 1) {
            if (*x >= cols - 1)
                return false;
            *x += 1;
        } else {
            *y += 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (*y <= 0) {
            if (*x >= cp->cols - 1)
                return false;
            *x += 1;
        } else {
            *y -= 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int rows, cols;

    printf("enter no. of rows of 1st matrix: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1 || rows < 1) {
        printf("invalid rows\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("enter no. of columns of 1st matrix: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &cols) != 1 || cols < 1) {
        printf("invalid columns\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int a[rows][cols];

    printf("\n enter the elements of 1st matrix");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid value for a[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // wave print
    int x, y;

    start_wave(&x, &y, cols, rows);
    for (;;) {
        printf("%d ", a[x][y]);
        if (!wave_next(&x, &y, cols, rows))
            break;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```